# How to define an Array property in a PHP class

Tags: php, arrays, function, oop

I have a following simple code but it produces syntax error on line `this->players[] = 'Tom'`:

```
    <?php

    class club {
            var $clubID = 0;        
            var $players=array();

            function __constructor($clubID = '') {              
                     $this->clubID = $clubID;
            } 

            function populatePlayers() {    
                     $this->players[] = 'Tom';
            }                                           
}

       $myClub = new club(1);
       $myClub->populatePlayers();
       var_dump($myClub->players);
?>
```

Comment: @Akshay, please take care when editing! You introduced a problem to the code that didn't exist beforehand, and now most answers are invalidated!

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
 $this->players[] = 'Tom';
```

instead of

```
$this->$players[] = 'Tom';
```

You need to add `$` before the `this` keyword and the `players` variable does not need one.

[Demo](https://eval.in/104496)

Comment: Even this give run time error :

Comment: @AmanKhanna, I don't think so.. See this https://eval.in/104496

Comment: Original question did not have the `$`. It was an editor error.

Comment: [`@Qantas`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2074608/qantas-94-heavy) , What's the reason for downvote ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function populatePlayers() {    
         $this->players[] = 'Tom';
}
```

Comment: You don't need to add `$` before `players` as it will result in a `FATAL` error.